# What is difference between START WAL LOCATION, STOP WAL LOCATION, and CHECKPOINT indicated in the backup history file?

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-10

I am a bit confused about these locations. Could someone give a short definition for these locations.

[image]

Comment: You may want to check [Making a Base Backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-BASE-BACKUP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Start WAL location” is the log sequence number (position in the WAL) where WAL replay starts when you recover the database.

“Stop WAL location” is the log sequence number where the backup ended. WAL has to be replayed at least to this point for the recovered data to become consistent. This is the earliest point to which you can recover (`recovery_target = 'immediate'`).

“Checkpoint location” is the log sequence number of the WAL entry of the checkpoint that starts the base backup.